Pac4j : where I can find the code for default login page
I have demo application for pac4j and when I am hitting the url http://localhost:8080/callback?client_name=IndirectBasicAuthClient
Its asking for credential in popup as below enter image description here
In code I have used below code for indirectBasicAuthClient
final IndirectBasicAuthClient indirectBasicAuthClient = new IndirectBasicAuthClient(new SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticator());
I am trying to find the code for default login page which is coming upon heating the url as shown in picture.
I am expecting location of the jar where default login page code is written

To display a form login page, you need to use the FormClient instead of the IndirectBasicAuthClient.

FormClient is to use custom login page correct ? I want to see which page is getting by default ? where is that code ? because if I am not using FormClient then also Login form

You can find the code in the pac4j-http dependency
